# Computer lags on simple tasks

Tags: windows-7, windows, performance

I have a Dell Precision M4600 mobile workstation laptop. I feel as though it is a very powerful computer, but it seems to react very slowly sometimes (Just playing a youtube video or opening a document). I'm thinking about going to another OS. The only thing I can think of is if there is anyway to make sure it's fully maxed out. what I mean by that is, I know a lot of processors clock themselves down until they really need it, but is there any way to force it to run at max? The reason why I believe it can be maxed is because it runs totally silent, and very very cool (Fans don't turn on, and very minimal heat).

Exact specs below

```
OS:
Windows 7 64-Bit SP1
CPU:
Intel Core i7 2820QM  @ 2.30GHz
Sandy Bridge 32nm Technology
RAM:
8.00 GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 665MHz (9-9-9-24)
Graphics:
2048MB Quadro 1000M
HDD:
125GB Samsung SSD
```

Comment: It's possible the hard drive is rooted. Open up Resource Monitor and look at disk queue lengths.

Comment: Disk queue length ranges from 0.01 to 0.05.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going into BIOS to disable speed step, that will force the CPU to run at max speed. Or set the power option in windows 7 to High Performance.

You can also download CPU-Z to confirm you current CPU speed http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

If you are still having problem after this, then it could be a software issue.

Comment: If I set it to high performance, is that as good as disabling speed step in BIOS? Just want to make sure, because you said "or", but you did not really mention which one will have more of an effect. Thanks!

Comment: Just an update: I disabled Intel Speed Step technology and I loaded up Win 7 again and I finally heard my fans (First time in a while). I'm going to use it like this for a while to see if I get any improvements. Thanks!

Comment: @ EGHDK,  It should be the same if you use high performance setting. Both action will cause your CPU to run at max speed full time.